# how to get apple's .P8 Certificate password?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to use .p8 file with aws, but when I upload my. .p8 file, it asks for password.
what should I have to write there?
Thank you

Comment: Talk to the guy who has gererated it.

Comment: @EL Tomato
im testing it using aws , but say wrong device token id, even it's correct